# Проблема с массивом

Tags: java

Добрый день, извините за нубский вопрос.

```
public class test {
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    String Alfavit = "АБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ";
    System.out.print("В алфавите "+Alfavit.length()+" символа\n");
    String[][] ar = new String[Alfavit.length()][Alfavit.length()];
    for (int i=0; i<=Alfavit.length(); i++)
    {
        int x = Alfavit.length(); 
        int y = i+1;
        for (int k=0; k<=i; k++)
        {
            ar[x][y]=Alfavit.charAt(i)+"";

            x--;
            y--;
        }
      }
}
}
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 33
at test.main(test.java:14)
```

Не могу понять в чем причина. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: а что вы хотите получить на выходе?

Comment: представьте что в алфавите у вас ровно один символ. сколько будет итераций в цикле и к каким индексам вы будете обращаться?  
нумерация идет с нуля до длины-1.

Comment: и почитайте [java code conventions][1], глаза режет, когда вижу переменные с большой буквы


   [1]: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка здесь:

```
for (int i=0; i<=Alfavit.length(); i++)
```

так как нумерация элементов массива начинается с нуля то индекс последнего элемента равен **длина минус единица**, Вы же пытаетесь получить элемент с индексом **длина** и из-за этого получаете ошибку, перевод которой звучит так:
Индекс массива вышел за границу